# Как центрировать блок  по горизонтали?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, javascript, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, отцентрировать всплывающее окно по горизонтали на этой [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/test4_modal).

Я пытаюсь применить метод на основе указания `width` и `margin: 0 auto`. Но не получается даже не смотря на то, что отменяю правило `left:` бла, которое добавляет  твиттер бутсрап

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить этому блоку `css` свойство

```
margin-left
```

Равное отрицательному значению половины ширины этого блока, т.е.:

```
#myModal {
   width: 300px;
   margin-left: - 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Файл: **bootstrap.min.css**, Строка: **743**. Для класса **.modal** заменяете:

  ```
  margin-left: -280px;
  width: 560px; // вообще лишнее
  ```

на следующее:

```
margin-left: -150px !important;
```

- Альтернативный вариант: найдите правило, которое у вас перекрывает этот *margin-left*

Comment: @Deonis уверены?

[![alt text][1]][2]


  [1]: http://upyourpic.org/images/201303/7mx24tje49_tn.jpg
  [2]: http://upyourpic.org/images/201303/7mx24tje49.png

Answer (score 1):

Ваш стиль, который описывает `#myModal`, перекрывает бутстраповский. Если его удалить - окно центрируется, но ширина возвращается к ширине по умолчанию.